# Possible to pass information to a browserfied file?

Tags: javascript, browserify

I have a set of widgets that are loaded dynamically depending on what the user requests. I have that aspect working (creating a script tag on the fly with the proper widget requested) as well as the browserification of the widgets into separate components.

My question is, is it possible to pass config information to the browserfied widget when it's loaded without using global variables?

For example:

```
var pageHead = document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0];
var script = document.createElement('script');
script.src = baseUrl +'/' + widget + '.js';
script.onload = function (event) {
    // do something here maybe to pass information into the 'ad' widget
    // for instance
};
pageHead.appendChild(script);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A good practice to pass configuration parameters to browsified widgets would be declare it in attributes.

```
<div prop1="abc" prop2="def" id="testwidget"></div>
```

and access them in javascript as required by using getAttribute() method...

```
document.getElementById("testwidget").getAttribute("prop1");
```

This will help you maintain configuration at the DOM level rather than keep a global variable.

Hope it helps!